# How to print inputted text in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, qemu, osdev

I am working on a little assembly project, and I'm running into some issues displaying inputted text. Here's the code I have so far:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov ah, 0
int 0x16
mov al, [key]
int 0x10

key:
    db 0

jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just doing operations in the wrong order, though I don't know in which way. For a bit more context, I'm using NASM to convert to a .bin, and QEMU to run the program.

Comment: Will you please provide your NASM and QEMU commands as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mov ah, 0` `int 0x16` instructions wait for a keypress.
To store the result you get in the AX register, you need to write `mov [key], al` with the destination as the leftmost operand.

If you want to output the character then just having `int 0x10` is not enough! You need to specify a function number and possibly also some additional parameters.

```
mov bx, 0007h   ; DisplayPage 0, ColorAttribute 7
mov al, [key]   ; ASCII code
mov ah, 0Eh     ; BIOS.Teletype
int 0x10
```

### Very important 1

Because you address a memory variable at *key*, you need to have the DS segment register setup correctly. In accordance with the `[org 0x7c00]` directive, you need DS=0.
Write the following first:

```
[org 0x7C00]
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
```

### Very important 2

The `jmp $` instruction must be on the execution path. You have placed it below the *key* data. Remember that **data is not to be executed**.

```
jmp $
key:
    db 0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa
```